# CKEditor set config.toolbar per instance

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've read through [the guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) but still am not sure how to change `toolbar` to point to a different setup.

My `config.js.coffee`:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = (config) ->
  config.extraPlugins = 'lite'
  config.toolbar_Basic = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   items: [ 'PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     items: [ 'Replace' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Subscript','Superscript' ] },
  config.toolbar_Advanced = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   items: [ 'PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     items: [ 'Replace' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Subscript','Superscript' ] },
    { name: 'lite', items: [ 'lite-toggletracking', '-', 'lite-acceptall', 'lite-acceptone', '-', 'lite-rejectall', 'lite-rejectone' ] },
  ]
  config.toolbar = 'Basic'
  lite = config.lite = config.lite || {}  
  true
```

Is there an easy way to select between `Basic` and `Advanced` toolbars per instance? Ideally I could use something like a class added to `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

When invoking `CKEditor`, specify the `toolbar` for an individual `CKEditor` instance as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', { toolbar: 'Basic' });
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor2', { toolbar: 'Advanced' });
```